How to ensure that a pair of keys from the smaller and larger dataset are hashed to the same partition in Spark?
I am reading the "Learning Spark" book. They say to use broadcast hash joins when "each key within the smaller and larger data sets is hashed to the same partition by Spark".
How exactly do I know/ensure whether these keys from the smaller and larger data sets are hashed to the same partition?
What does it even mean for those keys to be hashed to the same partition? And why exactly does that matter?

Seems an odd quote, I would disregard it. The 'smaller' aspect is only relevant imo.
Long story, short: In a 'broadcast hash join' there is no requirement to partition/hash the smaller data set as the whole point is that the smaller data set is broadcast in its entirety to all Worker Nodes with Executors that process partitions of the larger data set. There is no shuffling needed for bigger data set either, even though some sites state that, makes no sense. See excellent https://towardsdatascience.com/strategies-of-spark-join-c0e7b4572bcf on br hsh jn.
Poorly worded.

Hey thanks for the answer. you only explained the "broadcast" part of it - what does hashing got to do with this join?

Nothing as my description says.
